# Как реализовать MVVMi в Android на java

Tags: android-room, viewmodel, mvvm-android

Подскажите пожалуйста с чего начинать строить приложение по архитектуре mvvmi. Как работать с сущностью если в ней несколько ключей. По материалу прочитал уже несколько статей и просмотрел несколько докладов. разбирался по руководству на коделаб https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#3

сущность User

```
public class User {

    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    private String lastName;

    private String firstName;

    public User( @NonNull String lastName, String firstName){
        this.lastName=lastName;
        this.firstName=firstName;
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getLastName(){
        return lastName;
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getFirstName(){
        return firstName;
    }
}
```

интерфейс UserDao

```
public interface UserDao {
    @Insert
    void addUser(User person);

    @Delete
    void removeUser(User person);

    @Update
    void updateUser(User person);

    @Query("select * from User")
    LiveData<List<User>> getUser();
}
```

UserModel

```
public class UserModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private UserRepository mRepository;
    private LiveData<List<User>> mAllUsers;

    public UserModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);

        mRepository = new UserRepository(application);
        mAllUsers = mRepository.getAllUser();
    }

    LiveData<List<User>> getAllUsers(){
        return mAllUsers;
    }

    void insert (User user){
        mRepository.insert(user);
    }
}
```

UserRepository

```
public class UserRepository {

    private UserDao mUserDao;
    private LiveData<List<User>> mAllUser;

    UserRepository(Application application){
        DatabaseUser db = DatabaseUser.getDatabase(application);
        mUserDao = db.getUserDao();
        mAllUser = mUserDao.getUser();
    }

    LiveData<List<User>> getAllUser(){
        return mAllUser;
    }

    void insert(User user){
        DatabaseUser.databaseWriteExecutor.execute(()->{
            mUserDao.addUser(user);
        });
    }
}
```

DatabaseUser

```
@Database(entities = {User.class},version = 1, exportSchema =false)
public abstract class DatabaseUser extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract UserDao getUserDao();

    private static volatile DatabaseUser INSTANCE;
    private static final int NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 4;
    static final ExecutorService databaseWriteExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_THREADS);

    static DatabaseUser getDatabase(final Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (DatabaseUser.class) {
                if (INSTANCE == null) {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), DatabaseUser.class, "User")
                            .addCallback(sRoomDatabaseCallback)
                            .build();
                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private static RoomDatabase.Callback sRoomDatabaseCallback = new RoomDatabase.Callback(){
        @Override
        public void onOpen(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db ){
            super.onOpen(db);

            databaseWriteExecutor.execute(()->{
                UserDao dao = INSTANCE.getUserDao();

                User user = new User("Вася", "Петров");
                dao.addUser(user);

            });
        }

    };
}
```

активити MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private UserModel mWordViewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        // Get a new or existing ViewModel from the ViewModelProvider.
        mWordViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(UserModel.class);

        // Add an observer on the LiveData returned by getAlphabetizedWords.
        // The onChanged() method fires when the observed data changes and the activity is
        // in the foreground.
        mWordViewModel.getAllUsers().observe(this, new Observer<List<User>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<User> words) {
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Конкретизируйте пожалуйста вопрос по поводу "с сущностью если в ней несколько ключей". Пример и желаемый результат будут очень полезны для понимания как Вам помочь.

Comment: Вот такого вида у меня сущность, я хочу выводить имя и фамилию в разные textView

Comment: По вашей версии получается что  фамилия первичный ключ. Значит если Вам захочется создать еще одну запись с такой фамилией - то это не получится. Вы этого хотите добиться?

Comment: При этом "Вася" это фамилия?..

Comment: нет, спасибо что вы это подметили, об этом я не подумал, я добавил код который я написал этот проект я сделал в целях тренировки чтобы разобраться как работает архитектура и что за чем надо делать, застрял на том моменте когда надо выводить данные на UI

Comment: Понял, тогда это не критично. А что именно с выведением в UI не выходит?

Comment: Не видно где Вы в текствью данные пушите.

Comment: насколько понял надо делать вывод в активити в onChanged, но как правильно это написать не понимаю, делал так `TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
                textView.setText(User);` вот так не работает подчеркивает User по несоответствию типов

Comment: Так User Это класс. words - список того что Вы получили с базы. Чтобы получить строкове данные  поштучно и засетить их в разные текстовые поля, то нужно сначала получить элемент списка, а потом воспользоваться методами геттерами которые есть в классе User. Они вернут Вам нужные данные в стринговом виде. Вот их то и нужно засетить в Ваши TextView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробуйте так делать вывод:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private UserModel mWordViewModel;

TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Get a new or existing ViewModel from the ViewModelProvider.
    mWordViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(UserModel.class);

    // Add an observer on the LiveData returned by getAlphabetizedWords.
    // The onChanged() method fires when the observed data changes and the activity is
    // in the foreground.
    mWordViewModel.getAllUsers().observe(this, new Observer<List<User>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<User> words) {

            textView.setText(words.get(0).getLastName() + " " + words.get(0).getFirstName());

        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: вываливается в ошибку FATAL EXCEPTION, думаю что это связано с тем что пытаюсь выводить в общем потоке информацию в UI

Comment: Для начала попробуйте просто данные получить и например в ЛОГ вывести.  Так будет ясно что код до этого момента работает корректно. Потом уже будете передавать в textView.

Comment: @LEON пробуйте так.

Comment: @LEON Та и вообще лучше поискать более понятные туториалы чем от гугла. например https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components.html

Comment: еще вот такой вопрос интересует, лучше же делать с databinding и подписывать на LiveData или это и есть подпись на LiveData

Comment: @LEON это немного разные вещи. Почитайте уроки по ссылке выше. Там есть урок №18. Он как раз на эту тему.